# Rails 6.0 Resque Redis and Auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

Im using rails 6.0 with resque, redis and I can't get rails server to start because i've got AUTH issues and get the following when i start rails server

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/redis-4.6.0/lib/redis/client.rb:162:in `call': NOAUTH Authentication required. (Redis::CommandError)
```

i've tried putting the following into config/initializers/resque.rb and i've also tried it in environment.rb

```
Resque.redis = Redis.new(:password => 'myresquepassword')
```

If i fire up cli and put the the password in I can run commands no bother

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The answeris that resque does not have support for authentication in 2.2.1, so its not possible

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).